# Why are some devs placing the script tag in the bottom of the document?

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it practically good to put JS files at the bottom of webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814301/is-it-practically-good-to-put-js-files-at-the-bottom-of-webpage)

I've seen HTML documents where the developers place the `<script src="xxx">` tags in the bottom of the document and is wondering why.

I've just read HTML4 specification regarding the [script tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-html40-19980424/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1). It says nothing about when and how the script should be loaded. Hence it's up to the web browser to handle that as it sees fit.

Isn't it reasonable to think that the browser authors should be aware of that loading scripts synchronously or in any other way hinder the document rendering would affect the browsing experience?

i.e. aren't we as web developers better off to put the scripts in the `<head>` tag?

Comment: Question for people that answered this: If you place your js in a `$(document).ready{}` doesn't that prevent all of these negative effects? in other words, doesn't this wait for the page to load before executing the scripts?

Comment: @iight - there is a different between execution of code at the right time (which of course is very important) with the physical download/parsing of script. This takes time, even if it doesn't yield visible effects until some part of the script is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scripts require interpretation (which can be comparatively expensive) and may optionally require retrieval via another HTTP request. Placing them at the end of the document allows the rest of the page to load first.

> Scripts without async or defer attributes are fetched and executed
>   immediately, before the browser continues to parse the page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/script

See also http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-script-element.html, specifically the areas around preparation/blocking which are covered in detail. Note that this is an editor's draft in flux; some of these rules may not be in the final specification or be enforced by all user agents.

As a side note, this blocking behavior is not bad/wrong. Think of a library like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), which *does* belong in the `head`. It alters the DOM in a way that allows CSS to be correctly applied; were it executed in parallel, the results would be incorrect.

Comment: That's HTML5 specific, although it answers the question for that version. +1

Comment: Yes, it pertains to HTML5 (also added a link to the relevant HTML5 spec), but most (all?) browsers seem to follow those rules. In many cases HTML5 does a better job of codifying what browsers are already doing.

Answer (score 3):

Putting script tags at the top of a document can block the loading of rest of the page; this is especially true of banner ad scripts. If a third-party script takes a long time to load, any DOM element after that is delayed, resulting in a blank/malformed page until the request times out, or the content eventually loads.

Comment: How did you reach that conclusion?

Comment: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/27/loading-scripts-without-blocking/ - generally speaking, standalone JS files (rather than plugins) tend to be self-executing; they're loaded, and the final line executes whatever code they contain. If something in that code requires external resources - images, code, whatever - then the browser's single thread will pause until the script can be executed. This means no further code in the main page will be loaded until the JS has finished, leaving the page hanging.

Comment: That's a three year old post (IE8, Opera9 and old Chrome/WebKit). Isn't  scripts today jquery based (i.e. callback on document load)? So that basically applies to external scripts

Comment: Chances are that a large percentage of your users are still on older browsers that can/will still block loading until the script is downloaded.  We can't shame people just because they aren't on the latest update ;)

Comment: There was a big upset a little while back with a major ad-serving service serving buggy script which caused thousands of sites to hang, but I can't recall which one it was... sorry.

Comment: @RyanO'Neill: Yeah. I noticed that. 47% of IE users are still on IE8 :/.

Comment: Scripts block parallel downloads. If you have too many linked script files in your header, you may see the dreaded Flash of Unstyled Content while they download; adding them at the end of the document sidesteps this issue. It's a problem with the browser software, regardless of HTML doctype, and I'm not sure it's going away any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

This way the document will be fully displayed **before** the JavaScript code kicks in. If a script takes time or doesn't work or is unreachable it won't leave the user sitting in front of a blank page.

Also, doing DOM manipulations before the body element is fully loaded can produce an error IE.

Answer (score 0):

1. A JS script is executed at the point where it occurs in the page load. If it is at top of the page, the rest of the page won't have loaded when it runs, meaning that it won't be able to access any elements in the page.
2. If the script takes time to run (say, it has a slow loop, or throws up an `alert()` box, or does anything else that blocks execution), then the rest of the page loading will be delayed until it finishes. If the script is in the `<head>`, this can result in the user seeing a blank page while the script does it's thing.