# Is it still a good practice to put Javascript at the bottom using current technology

Tags: javascript, html

I am really new to web programming, and recently I started learning Javascript. I read a debate about where to put javascript, at top or at bottom. The top supporters emphasised that a slow loading is better than broken page since lack of js makes some of the features un-functional; the bottom supporters focused more on the loading speed, and argued that broken function could be warned by using css, which must get to load at the beginning. However, all the debate I've seen was at least 2 years (posts talking about this on SO was around [2009-2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638670/javascript-at-bottom-top-of-web-page), the latest i've seen is around [2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814301/is-it-practically-good-to-put-js-files-at-the-bottom-of-webpage)) from now, and html5 introduces new "async" and "defer" attribute to  tag in recent years. So my questions are:

Where is the best place to put your js, top or bottom **using the current technology, i.e. with async and defer**? If it depends, what kind of situation should you put js at the top/ bottom, and what kind of js should you put at the top/bottom?

Thanks very much!

Comment: This question is off-topic, because it is primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you want to use async where possible. Preference order : async>defer>no attribute.

When to use them?

**1)** Use `defer` if the script relies on another script(or the other way round)

**2)** Use `async` when the script can function on its own i.e it does not rely on other scripts.

**3)** If the script is small and is relied upon by an async script then use an `inline` script with no attributes placed above the async scripts.

Further reference @ https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element